# How to add pagination with page numbers rather than next/previous links?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, pagination

Does WordPress have any built-in pagination functions to show the page numbers instead of previous and next page links?

If not, how can I add that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on *which* pagination you're talking about:

- Archive Index pagination
- Single-Post pagination
- Comments pagination

In all three cases, the answer is **yes**, but the implementation is different.

**Archive Index Pagination**

WordPress provides a function, [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), for post-archive pagination links. It's use isn't exactly straightforward, but fortunately, implementation is mostly cut-and-paste from the Codex example.

[Here's how I use it in Oenology](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/custom.php#L1026).

**Single-Post Pagination**

WordPress provides a function, [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages), for intra-post pagination links. It's use is straight-forward, as a normal template tag.

**Comments Pagination**

WordPress provides a function, [`paginate_comments_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_comments_links), for comments pagination links. This template tag is actually a wrapper for `paginate_links()`, but its use is straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the WP page navi plugin. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/